# Using regex to find sentence between tags in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I need to get the sentence between tags like `<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello world!</p>` using **regex** .

Attribute of tags may differ like  `<p class="classname" style="color:blue">Hello world!</p>`

I have code like this

```
var result = elements.match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(function(val1){
    return val1.replace(/<\/?p>/g,'');
});
```

Comment: Don't use Regex to parse HTML!

Comment: Why you don't use DOM instead?

Comment: I don't have html as DOM element. I just have a word like <p class="test" style="color:red">Hello world!</p>

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use the DOM.

Comment: i just need it using regex

Comment: Again: ***Why***? Knowing that it doesn't work reliably? Knowing that [that way lies madness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247)? And if you really need a regex solution, you need to provide a **lot** more information about what may or may not be in the strings. for instance, can you have `<p>Foo<span>bar</span></p>` and, if so, what result do you expect?

Comment: i need the result from your string like `Foo<span>bar</span>`

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM instead of regex. You can use jquery to parsing string and get text of target element. Use [`jQuery.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to parse string into DOM or use only `jQuery()`.

```js
var html = '<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello world!</p>';
console.log($(html).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP has reconfirmed his requirement that he must use regex, so our answers are no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using

```js
function findPText(str, tag) {
  if (tag === void 0) {
    tag = "p";
  }
  var fullMatch = new RegExp('\<' + tag + '.*?<\\/' + tag + '>', 'ig').exec(str);
  var startMatch = new RegExp('\<' + tag + '.*?>', 'ig');
  var endMatch = new RegExp('\<\/' + tag + '\s*>', 'ig');
  var matches = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < fullMatch.length; index++) {
    var a = fullMatch[index];
    matches.push(a.replace(startMatch, '').replace(endMatch, ""));
  }
  return matches;
}
var str = '<h1 class="test" style="color:red">Hello world</h1>bob<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello World!</p>bob';
console.log(findPText(str, "h1"));
console.log(findPText(str, "p"));
```

Or render it as DOM:

```js
function findPText(str, tag) {
  if (tag === void 0) {
    tag = "p";
  }
  var myNode = document.createElement("body");
  myNode.innerHTML = str;
  var tags = myNode.querySelectorAll(tag);
  var matches = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < tags.length; index++) {
    var element = tags[index];
    matches.push(element.textContent);
  }
  return matches;
}

var str = '<h1 class="test" style="color:red">Hello <b>world</b></h1>bob<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello World!</p>bob';
console.log(findPText(str, "h1"), findPText(str, "p"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below regex works for you. Let me know if it does.

```
    var result = elements.match(/<p(.*?)<\/p>/g).map(function (val1) {
    return val1.replace(/<\/?p.*?>/g, '');
    });
```

.*? -> Matches all the characters(attribute properties) within the tag element.

If there are multiple tags in your element block, this will return you the array of texts. You could access them using their index

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this to get the text inside the `<p>` tags, depending on how your tags are formatted:

```
var el = '<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello world!</p>';
var re = /<p class=".*?" style="color:.*?">(.*?)<\/p>/g;
result = re.exec(el);
console.log(result[1]);
```

If you don't know what you're going to get inside the `<p>` tag, you can do something like this instead:

```
var el = '<p class="test" style="color:red">Hello world!</p>';
var re = /<p .*?>(.*?)<\/p>/g;
result = re.exec(el);
console.log(result[1]);
```

Of course, this assumes that there will never be other tags inside the `<p>` tag.